# Occasional issue with asynchronous callback

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I have a process that runs asynchronously every morning to download a file from an FTP site. The process works fine most of the time, but occasionally it will not complete, so I have been trying to add logs to figure out what is happening. As far as I can tell, the callback just randomly won't execute. Here is the relevant code:

```
Private Sub EndGetStreamCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim state = CType(ar.AsyncState, FtpState)

    Try
        Dim responseStream As Stream = state.ResponseStream
        Dim bytesRead = responseStream.EndRead(ar)
        Dim result As IAsyncResult
        Dim complete = CInt((state.BytesRead / state.FileSize) * 100)

        If bytesRead > 0 Then
            If complete > 95 Then
                Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "EndGetStreamCallback: " & bytesRead & " bytes read. (" & complete & "%)")
            End If

            state.File.Write(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            state.BytesRead += bytesRead
            If _callback IsNot Nothing Then
                _callback.StepTo(complete)
            End If
            lblCurrentProcess.Text = "Downloading Price Updates (" & complete.ToString() & "%)"
            result = responseStream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, 4096, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf EndGetStreamCallback), state)

            If complete > 95 Then
                Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "EndGetStreamCallback: after BeginRead()")
            End If

            If result Is Nothing Then
                Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "Fetch Price Updates: IAsyncResult Is Nothing")
            End If
            Return
        Else
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "EndGetStreamCallback: 0 bytes read, file download complete.")

            state.File.Flush()
            state.File.Close()
            state.OperationComplete.Set()
            responseStream.Close()
            state.Response.Close()

            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "Beginning to apply price udpate.")
            Call ClearSemaphore("PriceUpdate")
            Call BeginPriceUpdate(state.FilePath)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "EndGetStreamCallback (Price Update): " & ex.Message, ex)
        MessageBox.Show("Could not get the request stream." & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message)
        state.OperationException = ex
        state.OperationComplete.Set()
        If _callback IsNot Nothing Then
            _callback.End()
        End If
        Call ClearSemaphore("PriceUpdate")
    End Try
End Sub
```

As you can see, once the download completes, it should report `0 bytes read, file download complete` and begin to apply the update. However, sometimes it will just stop at 98, 99, or recently, I had it hit 100% and just not reach the completed section (the `Else`). I have been trying to figure this out for quite a while, but I'm not sure where else to look, as the method is just calling back to itself. No exceptions are thrown, it just stops (or hangs on another thread, I can't tell), but it does not complete once in a while. There doesn't seem to be any pattern that I'm noticing. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While I don't see your problem (perhaps you need some sort of timeout??) it looks like you're trying to apply the update from a callback.  That's might blow up in your face if you're doing something with that state file when this triggers.

Comment: `BeginPriceUpdate()` is just another method that starts a separate asynchronous process which applies the update from the downloaded file. Do you have a recommendation for a different way of starting the process?

Comment: I'm having a problem with the notion of applying a disruptive (you have that file close) update asynchronously, period.  You need to ensure the user isn't in the middle of something when you do that.